# Cannot pass value to Codeigniter controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am having a trouble while sending a value from an input element to Codeigniter controller by using ajax.

Since I have to use WYSIWYG editor ([summernote](http://summernote.org/getting-started/#get-amp-set-code)), thus I can just receive the input inside a `<script>`. However when I press the submit button, it just reloads the current page rather than the one in the controller.
Here is my code:

**PHP view**

```
<section id="mainContent">    
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" id="textbox" class="editor" name="textbox">
        <input id="submit_btn" type="button" name="sutmit" value="submit" onclick="myFunction()">
    </form>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var markupStr = $('#textbox').summernote('code');
        alert(markupStr);
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : "<?= site_url().'cintern/save'; ?>",
            async : false,
            data : {'iDes': markupStr},
            success : function(data){
                alert("Success!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    };
</script>
```

**PHP controller**

```
public function save() 
    {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['id'] = $session_data['idlogin'];
        $data['role'] = $session_data['role'];
        $data['pageTitle'] = 'Success';
        $data['iDes'] = $this->input->post('iDes');
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('internship/success', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

Please help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onsubmit` of `<form>` tag instead.

```
<section id="mainContent">    
  <form method="post" onsubmit="myFunction()">
    <input type="text" id="textbox" class="editor" name="textbox">
    <input id="submit_btn" type="button" name="sutmit" value="submit">
  </form>
</section>
```

The reason is, if you handle the `onclick` of your `<input type="submit">`, you can't intercept request of `<form>` tag after submit data.

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using JQuery for the ajax I suggest you use it to capture the submit also.

Remove the inline onclick assignment. Give the form an id attribute.

```
<section id="mainContent">    
    <form method="post" id="target">
        <input type="text" id="textbox" class="editor" name="textbox">
        <input id="submit_btn" type="button" name="sutmit" value="submit">
    </form>
</section>
```

Turn `myfunction()` into a 'submit' event handler

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#target").submit(function (event) {
  var markupStr = $('#textbox').summernote('code');
  //stop the normal submit from happening
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?= site_url().'cintern/save'; ?>",
    async: false,
    data: {'iDes': markupStr},
    success: function (data) {
      //do stuff with data then redirect to 'after_save' 
      console.log(data.results, data.otherstuff);
      window.location.href = "http://example.com/cintern/after_save";
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

Controller:

```
public function save() 
{
   $data = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
   // $data is now a semi-sanitized version of $_POST
   $_SESSION['iDes'] = $data['iDes'];
   //do other stuff with $data
   echo json_encode(['results' => "success", 'otherstuff' => $foo]);
}

  public function after_save()
  {
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $data['id'] = $session_data['idlogin'];
    $data['role'] = $session_data['role'];
    $data['pageTitle'] = 'Success';
    $data['iDes'] = $session_data['iDes'];
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('internship/success', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
  }
```